# Why scale() method of bigDecimal returning negative value when combining with stripTrailingZeros() method?

Tags: java, android, bigdecimal

To avoid the value like 10.0000 for `BigDecimal`, I used `stripTrailingZeros()` method which returns value 10 instead of 10.0000 as expected. Now, the scale of 10 should be 0 because for zero or positive value, the scale is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point. However, that is not the case as it is returning -1.

```
Log.d("click", BigDecimal("10").toPlainString()) // return 10
Log.d("click", BigDecimal("10").stripTrailingZeros().toPlainString()) // return 10
```

Above code return, same value 10 and `stripTrailingZeros()` has no effect on their value.

```
Log.d("click", BigDecimal("10").scale().toString())  // return 0
Log.d("click", BigDecimal("10").stripTrailingZeros().scale().toString()) // return -1
```

But the scale of those value is different as it is returning 0 and -1 and also

```
Log.d("click", BigDecimal("100").stripTrailingZeros().scale().toString()) // return -2
Log.d("click", BigDecimal("1000").stripTrailingZeros().scale().toString()) // return -3
```

Is there any way I can get my expected result? Can anybody explain why `scale()` method returning a negative value?

Comment: To fully understand the answer to this question, one would probably have to look into the source code for `BigDecimal` to see how `scale` is used, and why a negative scale is significant.

Comment: A number like 1e70 is stored as UnscaledValue of 1 and a scale of -70. Its precision is 1.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: It can be found out without looking at the source code too (just reads the docs and examine unscaledValue and scale for several values). But see my answer. It explains this.

Answer (score 7):

That is due to how a BigDecimal is stored. It uses a scale to remember the number of decimals.

### unscaledValue and scale

Bigdecimals can rememeber the number of decimals (places behind the decimal separator) it has. To do this, it they are stored as two values:

- an **unscaledValue** (usually a BigInteger, but for small values this can be a long too) that contains the (significant) digits and
- a **scale** (**the *negative* power of 10 to multiply the *unscaledValue* with to get the nominal value**, i.e. a kind of negative exponent).

Examples: the value *1.0* is stored as an UnscaledValue (I'll call it UV) of 10 and a scale of 1 (*10 x 10<sup>-1</sup>*). The value *3.000* is stored as an UV of 3000 and a scale of 3 (*3000 x 10<sup>-3</sup>*), *12.34* as UV=1234 and scale=2 (i.e. *1234 x 10<sup>-2</sup>*), and so on.

Your value *10* is stored as UV=10 and scale=0 (short: UV=10, s=0). But if you strip the trailing zeroes, you convert e.g. *1.000* (UV=1000, S=3) you strip the trialing zeroes from the UV and adjust the scale accordingly, so it becomes (UV=1, S=0): UV loses 3 zeroes, scale is adjusted to 0.

**Negative scales can be used too**, to denote (*positive*) powers of 10. The value *2e20* is stored as UV=2, s=-20 (*2 x 10<sup>20</sup>*), and not as UV=200000000000000000000, s=0. This saves a lot of space. Equally, *2.00e20* is stored as UV=200, s=-18, or *200 x 10<sup>18</sup>*.

That is why, when trailing zeroes are removed, *10* becomes UV=1, s=-1 (*1 x 10<sup>1</sup>*), instead of UV=10, s=0 (*10 x 10<sup>0</sup>*). And *6000* (UV=6000, s=0) becomes *6E+3* (UV=6, s=-3; *6 x 10<sup>3</sup>*).

### Setting the scale

But you can easily set the scale back to 0 without changing the nominal value. If the scale was negative, no rounding will occur.

```java
BigDecimal b1 = new BigDecimal("10.000"); // UV=10000, s=3, 10000 x 10**-3
System.out.println(b1);
b1 = b1.stripTrailingZeros();             // UV=1, s=-1, *all* trailing zeros removed,
                                          // as desired: 10000 --> 1
System.out.println(b1);
b1 = b1.setScale(0);                      // UV=10, s=0
System.out.println(b1);
```

Output:

```
10.000
1E+1
10
```

So to strip the trailing decimal zeros only, do:

```java
b1 = b1.stripTrailingZeros();
if (b1.scale() < 0)
  b1 = b1.setScale(0);
```

Comment: greate explain!